# stat report combining data from 3 tables - join or subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, join, subquery

I have three tables: tbl_Player, tbl_MatchDetails, tbl_MatchStat with some data:

tbl_Player

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Player](
    [PlayerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Player] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PlayerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Player] ON
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Player] ([PlayerID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'L Messi')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Player] ([PlayerID], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'C Ronaldo')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Player] ([PlayerID], [Name]) VALUES (3, N'Neymar')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Player] ([PlayerID], [Name]) VALUES (4, N'Rooney')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Player] ([PlayerID], [Name]) VALUES (5, N'K Aguero')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Player] ([PlayerID], [Name]) VALUES (6, N'Gomez')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Player] OFF
```

tbl_MatchDetails

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails](
    [MatchID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Tournament] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TeamA] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TeanB] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_MatchDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MatchID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails] ON
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails] ([MatchID], [Tournament], [TeamA], [TeanB]) VALUES (1, N'CL', N'Real', N'Barca')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails] ([MatchID], [Tournament], [TeamA], [TeanB]) VALUES (2, N'CL', N'Barca', N'United')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails] ([MatchID], [Tournament], [TeamA], [TeanB]) VALUES (3, N'League', N'Barca', N'Real')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails] ([MatchID], [Tournament], [TeamA], [TeanB]) VALUES (4, N'CL', N'M City', N'Bayern')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails] ([MatchID], [Tournament], [TeamA], [TeanB]) VALUES (5, N'League', N'Barca', N'Valencia')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails] ([MatchID], [Tournament], [TeamA], [TeanB]) VALUES (6, N'League', N'Real', N'Betis')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchDetails] OFF
```

tbl_MatchStat

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat](
    [StatID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MatchID] [int] NULL,
    [PlayerID] [int] NULL,
    [Goals] [int] NULL,
    [Minutes] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_MatchStat] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StatID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ON
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 3, 92)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1, 92)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (3, 2, 1, 2, 85)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (4, 2, 4, 2, 93)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (5, 3, 1, 1, 35)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (6, 3, 2, 0, 90)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (7, 4, 6, 2, 93)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (8, 4, 5, 0, 15)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (9, 5, 3, 2, 25)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (10, 5, 1, 4, 91)
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] ([StatID], [MatchID], [PlayerID], [Goals], [Minutes]) VALUES (11, 6, 2, 3, 88)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_MatchStat] OFF
```

From this data i wanted to have a select statement which gives a summary of each player by tournament. For eg,  from this data selecting by tournament 'CL' the query result may looks like

```
Name       MatchPlayed TotalGoals HighestScore Minutes Hattrick
L Messi              2          5            3     117        1
C Ronaldo            1          1            1      92        0
Rooney               1          2            2      93        0         
K Aguero             1          0            0      15        0
Gomez                1          2            2      93        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT p.Name, 
       COUNT(m.MatchID) MatchPlayed, 
       SUM(s.Goals) TotalGoals,
       MAX(s.Goals) HighestScore,
       SUM(s.Minutes) Minutes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.Goals >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Hattrick
  FROM tbl_MatchDetails m JOIN tbl_MatchStat s
    ON m.MatchID = s.MatchID JOIN tbl_Player p
    ON s.PlayerID = p.PlayerID
 WHERE m.Tournament = 'CL'
 GROUP BY p.Name
```

Output:

```
|      NAME | MATCHPLAYED | TOTALGOALS | HIGHESTSCORE | MINUTES | HATTRICK |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| C Ronaldo |           1 |          1 |            1 |      92 |        0 |
|     Gomez |           1 |          2 |            2 |      93 |        0 |
|  K Aguero |           1 |          0 |            0 |      15 |        0 |
|   L Messi |           2 |          5 |            3 |     177 |        1 |
|    Rooney |           1 |          2 |            2 |      93 |        0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86b4f/7)** demo

Comment: Thank you very much, i was totally confused with joins for 3 tables. i got it. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for adding queries but i was wondering how to calculate if player have played full match or not, logic is if he had played 90 or more minutes than that should be counted. i  tried like

COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Minutes>= 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FullMatch

Comment: I think i have done with it i should use SUM instead of COUNT, am i right. Thanks again

Comment: @barcanoj Yes you need to use `SUM()` for that